# When a samba server shares NFS4 mount directory, window clients cannot copy file. ERROR: 0x80070021

Tags: samba, nfs

The error reported by windows client is like this `ERROR: 0x80070021 The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.`

I google it and hit [samba bug report 8481](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8481)  .
Which is very similar to this problem. 
[Another link](http://omging1982.blogspot.fi/2012/08/nfs-error-code-0x80070021.html) also mentions a similar issue.

But, instead of NFSv3, my NFS backend is using NFSv4,  provided by OpenSolaris ZFS file system.

I try to `mount -t nfs4 -o nolock fileserver:/export/home /home`, but it says `no such option "nolock"`. `nolock` is only valid for NFSv3, not NFSv4.

1. fileserver: an OpenSolaris file server.
2. Linux server: Debian Lenny. Running `samba` service and mount `/home` to `fileserver:/export/home`
3. Windows client: it can browse the directories shared by the linux server, but cannot copy any files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I found googling, this is a problem caused on NFS level, to fix it edit `/etc/samba/smb.cfg`  and in the `[global]` section add the option:

```
strict locking = no
```